# Comparing Text Rendering in Skia: SkCanvas's drawSimpleText vs. SkParagraph's drawParagraph

Tags: skiasharp, skia, skiacanvas

Why does painting the text "" on an SkSurface using SkCanvas's `drawSimpleText` method result in the emoji not being painted, while using SkParagraph's `drawParagraph` method prints everything correctly?

Additionally, when printing the word "utilizes" in both variants, the font appears better with SkCanvas's `drawSimpleText` compared to SkParagraph's `drawParagraph`. Why is there such a difference in text rendering between these two methods, given that they should theoretically produce identical results?

**SkCanvas's drawSimpleText:**

[image]

**SkParagraph's drawParagraph:**

[image]